# Ruby on Rails: Cannot Activate tmail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

`Gem::LoadError: can't activate tmail (= 1.2.3.1), already activated tmail-1.2.7.1. Make sure all dependencies are added to Gemfile.`

I get this when I run a certain rake task. I've added it to the Gemfile, and I've already run `gem uninstall tmail` and `gem install tmail`.

Answer (score 0):

After updating your `Gemfile` always run `bundle install`.

Also, when `bundle install` not help, try deleting your Gemfile.lock (file) and then do `bundle install`.

When that not fix your issue try to run `bundle update` for resolving dependencies, but that command can update all gems, so be careful with this task.